# get owning PID for socket fd

Tags: file, sockets, networking, file-descriptor

Is there an Linux API that would return PID/PIDs of processes owning an open socket file descriptor? For now the only way I see is walking `/proc/PID/fd` for every PID and derive socket `fd` by `inode`.

However I have not seen any syscall/API that would do this for example:

`int get_pids_for_socket(int sock_fd, int pids[])`

(Very rough idea of course). What are the reasons such API doesn't exist, or I was not looking well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is meaningless. FDs are not unique across processes. Any given FD value could belong to hundreds of processes. Sockets are uniquely identified by 4-tuples, not FDs.

Comment: I don't care about 4-tuples, I want to know which process opened the socket identified by `FD`.

Comment: So you didn't understand what I wrote. The socket *isn't* identified by a FD.